# How do I link to external images in my WP posts

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I am scraping a site and putting data in my WP site.

There are lots of images in those posts.

I want that when importing that scraped data into my WP site, 
I want to link images into my site directly from that external URL instead of downloading image to my server.

I am grammatically importing scraped data to my site.

Here is that part of adding image

```
    // for image
    $ins_q = "INSERT INTO wpxw_posts (post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_status, "
            . "comment_status, ping_status,"
            . "post_password, post_name, to_ping, pinged, post_modified,post_modified_gmt, post_content_filtered,post_parent,"
            . "guid,menu_order,post_type,"
            . "post_mime_type,comment_count) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $sth = $conn->prepare($ins_q);
    if (!$sth->execute(array(
               $post_author, $date, $date, "", sanitize_title_with_dashes($image_name), "", "inherit", "open", "closed", '',
                str_replace(".", "-", $image_name), '', '', $date, $date, '', $post_id,
                "http://photos2.zillowstatic.com/p_f/ISdc6hruhctopo0000000000.jpg" 

                , 0, "attachment", "image/jpeg", 0
            ))) {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        print_r($sth->errorInfo());
        exit();
    }
```

}

**MY PROBLEM** is that when adding external link to image, images do not show on my post. How can I show images from external resources?

Comment: instead you can use wordpress function wp_insert_attachment.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add Featured Image to Post
$image_url  = 'http://s.wordpress.org/style/images/wp-header-logo.png'; // Define the image URL here
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); // Set upload folder
$image_data = file_get_contents($image_url); // Get image data
$filename   = basename($image_url); // Create image file name

// Check folder permission and define file location
if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
} else {
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
}

// Create the image  file on the server
file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

// Check image file type
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

// Set attachment data
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

// Create the attachment
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

// Include image.php
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

// Define attachment metadata
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

// Assign metadata to attachment
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

// And finally assign featured image to post
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

Comment: what this do ?? doesnt it saves image to my WP site?